# Lazy Loading Items in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, lazy-loading

I have two objects that have a many to many relationship with each other.

I'm using Entity Framework in a Database First approach.

My Database Profiler is showing that everytime I fetch one set of objects A, it loads the other set of object B for each element in A. I assumed that with lazy loading, this wouldn't happen, or that B would be fetched when accessing via the navigation property.

The code to access the objects uses a generic approach, where entities is my DbContext

```
public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
{
    IQueryable<T> query = entities.Set<T>();
    return query;
}
```

Both navigation properties are implemented as `virtual ICollection<T>` and I have `Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true` explicitly set in my `DbContext` constructor.

Am I missing something, or approaching this the wrong way? Should I just remove the navigation properties and explicitly load what I need via other queries?

Comment: Are you watching the loaded `A` elements in the debugger? Remember that you trigger lazy loading with the debugger when you watch the `A` elements with their `B` collections.

Comment: I set `LazyLoadingEnabled` to false and then the `B` collections aren't loaded, so I'm not sure why that is

Comment: It simply means that something in your code touches those navigation properties and executes lazy loading - as @Slauma mentioned even debugging tools are doing this.

Comment: Does calling `ToList()` on the `IQueryable` cause the lazy loading to be executed? Without using the debugger, and just using the SQL Server Profiler, I can see that each `A` object is having the `B` objects selected, and I don't actually use the navigation property anywhere

Comment: But this sounds more like eager loading. Are you using `Include` in your query?

Comment: No, it is the query I specified in the question (which is just `entities.Set<T>()`)

Comment: I don't believe Set should materialize the collection without being enumerated. Something is enumerating your set (causing the enumerator to MoveNext()). ToList, .AsEnumerable(), and a few other things can cause this. Inspecting in the debugger will also enumerate so that's not always a good way to check. If you don't see any method or loop that is causing enumeration, try doing something like returning it as IEnumerable<T> instead of IQueryable<T>

Answer (score 0):

In the presence of the experts I am reluctant to ask this :) but would setting ProxyCreationEnabled=false on the DbContext not help in this case? Sorry if this is too "newbish" of a point